# Making username and userid into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to my array, somthing like this:

```
array("userid"=>"username","1"=>"ganeshfriends","2"=>"tester")
```

mysql query something like this:

```
$query = select username, userid from tbluser

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $items = array($row['userid']=>$row['username']);
}
print_r($items);
```

How can I make userid as key and username as val?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to do and what doesn't work? As far as I can see, you already have the solution. Also, what does the first array have to do with the rest? Plus, there is no need to make questions like this Community Wiki.

Comment: What's your question?  Your code looks OK.  Also your question is a normal question, not community wiki.

Comment: I think the issue is that if he does it the way it's set up now, if there are multiple rows, he loses the previous array on each iteration, since it's not pushing to the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "select username, userid from tbluser";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$items=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $items[$row['userid']]=$row['username'];
}
print_r($items);
```

The problem is that you delete and reassign the result array ($items) in every loop of the while block

Comment: I don't understand the OP's question - `$items[key] = value` is identical to `$items = Array(key => value)` with the exception that the former will append to `$items` if it is already defined, while the latter will make `$items` a new array.  Also you've got a stray bracket after that line ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$items[$row['userid']]=$row['username']);` or is this a notation style I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to delete the ")"

Comment: @Andy Shellam: with the Array(key => value) form you reassign the $item variable every time while with $items[key] = value you create a new element in the array because the key is different every time

Comment: @mck89 - check out my pretty version of your answer.

Comment: @Andy Shellam: Sorry i missed that part

Answer (score 3):

Since everyone keeps suggesting the same thing, I figure I may as well join in.

When I have a situation with keys from sql values, I like to set them to variables first so it's nicer looking:

```
$query = "select username, userid from tbluser";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $userid = $row['userid'];
    $username = $row['username']
    $items[$userid] = $username;
}
print_r($items);
```

It may add two lines, but it sure is easier on the eyes and avoids brackets in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$arr = array('userid' => 'username');

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result) die("Query failed");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $arr[$row['userid']] = $row['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use other variables, like Anthony, i just want to say, don't remember about stripslashes(i think you've done mysql_real_escape_string() when writing them to tha database)

---

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $userid = $row['userid'];
    $username = stripslashes($row['username']);
    $items[$userid] = $username;
}
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() escapes values in the context of a query, it does not leave slashes in the database. A query of database values will return the value *without* slashes. Doing stripslashes() at that point will just remove legitimate slashes, instead.

Comment: when he writes "username" into database, (when using mysql_query("insert into ...")), he must use mysql_real_escape_string, for security reasons. to make safe query.
so then he must use stripslashes...

Answer (score 0):

since youre only using associative access i would propose the use of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

since you don't arg that you want an associative array given back by `mysql_fetch_array()` it creates 2 arrays, one with `int-indexes` and one with `string-indexes` (assoc[iative]), even though this short script doesn't use much memory and might have high speed, you should always remember the `performance`.